# YouTube Data API: What are all the parts and their fields?

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

In YouTube's Data API, data are returned in fields, and fields are grouped in parts. In the YouTube documentation, *[YouTube Data API Overview](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started)*, the section, *[How to use the part parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#part)*, gives a list of the parts available for videos:

- snippet, contentDetails, fileDetails, player, processingDetails, recordingDetails, statistics, status, suggestions, topicDetails

There are two things I have not found in the documentation:

- The list of parts available for channels and playlists.
- The list of fields available in each part for videos, channels, and playlists.

Where can I get that information?

Also, some fields are available to the public, while others are only available to the owner of the subject resource. So in the list of fields, I need to know which I can query and which are restricted.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer:

- Channels

  - Parts: [docs/channels/list#parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#parameters)
  - Fields: [docs/channels#properties](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#properties)
  - Restrictions: [docs/channels/list#auth](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#auth)
- Playlists

  - Parts: [docs/playlists/list#parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list#parameters)
  - Fields: [docs/playlists#properties](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists#properties)
  - Restrictions: If there are any, they don't seem to be documented.
- Playlist items

  - Parts: [docs/playlistItems/list#parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#parameters)
  - Fields: [docs/playlistItems#properties](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#properties)
  - Restrictions: If there are any, they don't seem to be documented.
- Videos

  - Parts: [docs/videos/list#parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#parameters) (The list at that link gives three additional parts that are not in the list at [*How to use the part parameter*](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#part): `id`, `liveStreamingDetails`, and `localizations`.)
  - Fields: [docs/videos#properties](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#properties)
  - Restrictions: Stated in the descriptions of the `fileDetails`, `processingDetails`, and `suggestions` fields.

===================================

Fields that are missing from my previous answer are

- contentDetails

  - regionRestriction
  - hasCustomThumbnail
- status

  - failureReason
  - rejectionReason
  - publishAt (But this should never appear in a public listing because it only applies to videos with `privacyStatus` = 'private`.)
  - selfDeclaredMadeForKids (But only returned if authorized.)
- statistics

  - dislikeCount (But only returned if authorized.)
- player

  - embedHeight
  - embedWidth
- recordingDetails

  - location
  - recordingDate
- liveStreamingDetails

  - 6 fields
- localizations

  - key (language)

Answer (score -1):

I have used a method to get a partial list of the public fields available for videos. This is a hack and I hope someone will post a better answer, preferably a link to the answer in official YouTube documentation.

Until we get that answer, here is the hack I used:

First, I took the list of the ten parts given for videos and submitted it in an API call for three arbitrary videos:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,contentDetails,fileDetails,player,processingDetails,recordingDetails,statistics,status,suggestions,topicDetails&id=XqZsoesa55w,kJQP7kiw5Fk,F4tHL8reNCs&key=<key>
```

The result was this error message:

> The request is not properly authorized to access video file or
> processing information. Note that the `fileDetails`,
> `processingDetails`, and `suggestions` parts are
> only available to that video's owner.

That is information. It tells me that those three parts are not publicly available, so I can't query them on videos I don't own.

So next I submitted the same request with those three parts removed:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,contentDetails,player,recordingDetails,statistics,status,topicDetails&id=XqZsoesa55w,kJQP7kiw5Fk,F4tHL8reNCs&key=<key>
```

I then took the response from that and parsed the JSON to extract the labels at the third and fourth level of nesting. These are mostly the part and field names. The first three rows of the following table are fields; the rest are parts with their constituent fields.

| Field or part | Field |
| --- | --- |
| kind |  |
| etag |  |
| id |  |
| snippet | publishedAt |
|  | channelId |
|  | title |
|  | description |
|  | thumbnails |
|  | channelTitle |
|  | tags |
|  | categoryId |
|  | liveBroadcastContent |
|  | defaultLanguage |
|  | localized |
|  | defaultAudioLanguage |
| contentDetails | duration |
|  | dimension |
|  | definition |
|  | caption |
|  | licensedContent |
|  | contentRating |
|  | projection |
| status | uploadStatus |
|  | privacyStatus |
|  | license |
|  | embeddable |
|  | publicStatsViewable |
|  | madeForKids |
| statistics | viewCount |
|  | likeCount |
|  | favoriteCount |
|  | commentCount |
| player | embedHtml |
| topicDetails | topicCategories |
| recordingDetails |  |

Notice that part `recordingDetails` has no fields listed. That doesn't mean it has no fields. It means that none of the videos for the IDs submitted have `recordingDetails` in their data. That is why I said at the beginning that what I've got is a partial list. It is only based on the data retrieved for those three videos. Another example of this issue is that only two of the three videos submitted have a `commentCount` in their data. If none of them had data for that field, then I would not know about the existence of that field from this exercise.

So there's my partial list of public fields for videos. Can someone give us a better answer pointing to documentation of all the fields for videos, channels, and playlists?